# How to determine which dependency causes Google Play OpenSSL warning?

Tags: android, openssl, google-play-services, android-security

I'm currently working on a big legacy project and trying to fix the OpenSSL vulnerability issue as explained at [How to address OpenSSL vulnerabilities in your apps](http://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6376725).

The problem is, there are lot of dependencies, some are open source (I updated all that didn't break the compatibility) added as Gradle import, some are custom/closed source provided by partners and contractors of the company I work for and attached to the project as JARs.

Is there any way to pinpoint specific library that has this vulnerability? I used the bash script provided at [Google Play and OpenSSL warning message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24295803/3734457) and it points to one native dependency (actually the .so file). Is there any option to pinpoint actual dependency from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any option to pinpoint actual dependency from there?

Yes, but you need to know the offending OpenSSL version and you need `grep`. Windows `find` won't do.

First, take note of the offending OpenSSL version. For sake of argument, say its due to ***`OpenSSL 1.0.1h`***.

Next, gather a list of your dependencies and their top level folders. For sake of argument, say its ***`$HOME/Desktop/aosp-app`***, ***`$HOME/sdk-a`***, ***`/usr/local/sdk-b`*** and ***`/opt/local/sdk-c`***.

Finally, for the top level directories:

```
grep -R '1.0.1h' "$HOME/Desktop/aosp-app"
grep -R '1.0.1h' "$HOME/sdk-a"
grep -R '1.0.1h' /usr/local/sdk-b
grep -R '1.0.1h' /opt/local/sdk-c
```

You *don't* need `grep -iR`, which is a case insensitive (`-i`) recursive (`-R`) search. You also don't need `grep -IR`, which is a recursive (`-R`) search that skips binary files (`-I`).

All of this works because OpenSSL library embeds its version in the data section as a string. Eventually, you will hit on the culprit, which is probably an SDK that comes pre-built as a shared object but includes OpenSSL as a static library. One SDK seems to be identified frequently, and it uses cURL which is built against a static OpenSSL library.

---

If you have [JAR files and suspect them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36213149), then you can perform the following as a quick test:

```
find <dir> -name '*.jar' -exec grep -R '1.0.1h' {} \;
```

The command will look in the directory `<dir>` and its subdirectories. It will search for files with the `*.jar` extension. When it finds one, it will run `grep` on it looking for the string. `find` will do it for every `*.jar` it finds.