# Android application is not updated latest version of OpenSSL

Tags: android, gradle, openssl, centos

I'm working on Android application in CentOS environment.
Someday ago, I already upgraded OpenSSL verion from 1.0.1h -> 1.0.2g
Version checking command is working fine!

> openssl version
>   OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

However, after application is built I check the OpenSSL version inside the app.
It's still using the old version of OpenSSL.

> unzip -p myApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSl"

A lot of string related to "1.0.1h" is showing

Has anyone seen this problem ?
Thanks

Comment: [Google Play and OpenSSL warning message](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24197777) or [How to check which dependancy causes OpenSSL vulnerability](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38187257).

Comment: Thank you so much !