# Application rejection due to OpenSSL

Tags: android, openssl, google-play

I tried to upload application on Play Store but the app got rejected and I got mail from Google Play with following issue:

[image]

I used many libraries, jars, external projects and dependencies in my app are.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':videorecording')
    compile project(':cropper')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.7.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile project(':recorder')
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.5'
    compile 'com.timehop.stickyheadersrecyclerview:library:0.4.3'
    compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.kyleduo.switchbutton:library:1.2.8'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.splunk.mint:mint:4.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.4'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip:target-tooltip-library:+'
    compile project(':uploadservice')
}
```

I searched a lot on google and got to know that I need to update OpenSSL version. I don't know how to update OpenSSL or which library in my project uses OpenSSL.

Comment: Check if all the dependencies are up to date.Most probably a 3rd party app is causing the issue . Check this link to find which one is casuing the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187257/how-to-determine-which-dependency-causes-google-play-openssl-warning/38190080#38190080

Comment: You seem to be using "UploadService" have you checked if the web service has ssl?

Comment: I would guess that a Twitter library would use OpenSSL in order to contact OpenSSL.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I got a ready and running project from one of my friend. Which is having many libraries used. In which all above libraries are included. Can any one suggest a way how to find out, which library using OPENSSL and which version of OPENSSL in library.