# Which dependency is causing Google Play warning message for OpenSSL?

Tags: android, openssl, google-play, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

My app rejected from Google Play because of **OpenSSL Vulnerability**. I don't specially use OpenSSL and I can't figure out which one of these dependencies causes the problem.

I am building on Windows 10.

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile group: 'cz.msebera.android', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'
    compile('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.3.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'net.ypresto.qtfaststartjava:qtfaststart:0.1.0'
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Where did this OpenSSL library come from that you are using?

Comment: Literally have no idea.

Comment: I would focus then on determining why you have it. If you did not add it yourself, presumably it is coming from some third-party dependency that you added to your app. Figure out what that is, and update to its newest version, as they probably have it fixed. If you cannot determine where this OpenSSL library is coming from, you have *far* bigger problems than getting it on a newer version.

Comment: Actually its pretty obvious its because of a 3rd party lib but i can't figure out which one. There are plenty of commands to find it on linux but there is no command line for windows

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, you might consider editing your question and posting the `dependencies` closure from your module's `build.gradle` file, and perhaps somebody will recognize which dependency pulls in OpenSSL.

Comment: edited, thanks for your suggestion, really appreciated.

Comment: Based off of names, I'd lean towards `com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0` as being the leading candidate. I am not aware that either OkHttp or HttpClient use an NDK-built OpenSSL. None of the others seem likely. `com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client` appears to be up to 0.7.0, so you might try moving to a newer version of it.

Comment: Removed socket.io and okhttp also used several batches and result was no openssl but Google play still rejects..

Comment: Also see [Google Play and OpenSSL warning message](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24197777), [How to grep or search .jar files for OpenSSL?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36213149) and [How to determine which dependency causes Google Play OpenSSL warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38187257)

Comment: Thanks jww, I used your links and saw that only classes.dex has OpenSSL. What to do now?

Comment: `classes.dex` is compiled Java byte code. You need to work back further, and determine where `Openssl.class` is coming from within `classes.dex`.

Comment: I figured out. The reason was libavformat.so using by ffmpeg.