# Google-Play rejection due to libpng security vulnerabilities

Tags: eclipse, security, google-play, android-security, libpg

I have an Eclipse project. When i exported the APK it worked perfectly, but when I publish it on google play it gave me this error:

> Libpng library
>
> The vulnerabilities were fixed in libpng v1.0.66, v.1.2.56, v.1.4.19,
>   v1.5.26 or higher. You can find more information about how resolve the
>   issue in [this Google Help Center article](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7011127).

But the article isn't helpfull at all.

Does Any one know how to fix this prob or where i can change the libpng version ?

Thank You.

Comment: This question is usually asked about OpenSSL and BoringSSL. The first thing to do is update everything to the latest, including Eclipse and all the SDKs you use. Also see [Google Play and OpenSSL warning message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24197777/608639), [How to determine which dependency causes Google Play OpenSSL warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38187257/608639) and [How to grep or search .jar files for OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36213149/608639)

Comment: Ido have the latest SDKs & Eclipse The google help center says "Please migrate your app(s) to libpng v1.0.66, v.1.2.56, v.1.4.19, v1.5.26 or higher as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded AP" 
How can i do that ??